# How to improve a SELECT statment that contains subqueries?

Tags: mysql, select, subquery

I made this SELECT, but I think it could be improved. Does anyone know how would be the best way to make it better?

```
 SELECT  SUBSTRING_INDEX(acctEmail, '@', -1) as Domain, 
        (SELECT count(*) FROM accounts 
            WHERE acctType = 'A' AND SUBSTRING_INDEX(acctEmail, '@', -1) = Domain
            GROUP BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(acctEmail, '@', -1)
        ) as qtdAlias,
        (SELECT count(*) FROM accounts 
            WHERE acctType = 'C' AND SUBSTRING_INDEX(acctEmail, '@', -1) = Domain
            GROUP BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(acctEmail, '@', -1)
        ) as qtdContas,
        (SELECT count(*) FROM accounts 
            WHERE acctType = 'L' AND SUBSTRING_INDEX(acctEmail, '@', -1) = Domain
            GROUP BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(acctEmail, '@', -1)
        ) as qtdListas,
        count(*) as Total
FROM accounts
GROUP BY Domain
ORDER BY Total DESC;
```

It brings the following result:

[image: Result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to make conditional sum as

```
select
substring_index(acctEmail, '@', -1) as Domain, 
sum(
 case when acctType = 'A' then 1 else 0 end
) as qtdAlias,
sum(
 case when acctType = 'C' then 1 else 0 end
) as qtdContas,
sum(
 case when acctType = 'L' then 1 else 0 end
) as qtdListas,
count(*) as Total
from accounts
GROUP BY Domain
ORDER BY Total DESC;
```

Comment: came here to post the same thing

Comment: Ha looks like we are having the same thoughts :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot, Abhik! It is mucher better than mine. From now I will start using your way.